# Populate Tabular form field value with change of another field

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle-apex, tabular-form

There is a Tabular form with `description, previous_value, unit_price` fields in my Oracle Apex app.

I need to populate value of `previous_value` field with data on `description` field. I have a query to get value for `previous_value` field from database. i need to add `onChange` event to `description` field. with the changes in `description` field, value for `previous_value` field should be populate using my query.

how could i do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the change event to the field in several ways. Target through the td headers,
or edit the column, and in the "Element attributes" field you could add a class (eg "fireAjax").
You can then bind to the event with either javascript code, or do this via a dynamic action.

You can do an ajax call in either of these 2 forms: through htmldb_Get or with jquery.post:

```
$('td[headers="ENAME"] input').change(function(){   
   var ajaxRequest = new htmldb_Get( null , $v('pFlowId') , 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_job' , $v('pFlowStepId'));
   ajaxRequest.addParam('x01', $(this).val());
   ajaxResult = ajaxRequest.get();
   $(this).closest("tr").find("td[headers='JOB'] input").val(ajaxResult);
});
```

OR

```
$('td[headers="ENAME"] input').change(function(){
var that = this;
$.post('wwv_flow.show', 
       {"p_request"      : "APPLICATION_PROCESS=get_job",
        "p_flow_id"      : $v('pFlowId'),
        "p_flow_step_id" : $v('pFlowStepId'),
        "p_instance"     : $v('pInstance'),
        "x01"            : $(this).val()
        },
        function(data){ 
           var eJob = $(that).closest("tr").find("td[headers='JOB'] input");
           eJob.val(data);
        },
        "text"
      );
});
```

With this application process, defined on the page with execution point "AJAX Callback":
Name: get_job

```
DECLARE
   l_job emp.job%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT job
   INTO l_job
   FROM emp
   WHERE ename = apex_application.g_x01;

   htp.p(l_job);
EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
   htp.p('');
END;
```

Remember, handling errors and return in this process is up to you! Make sure you catch common errors such as `no_data_found` and/or `too_many_rows`. If they occur and are not trapped, chances are big you will encounter javascript errors because your javascript callback code can not handle the error (which in apex will be a full page html with the error message in it).
Also, as you can see i'm using the `x01` variable, which is one of the 10 global temporary variables in apex. This way it is not required to use a page item and submit the value to session state for it.

If you want to put this code in a dynamic action you can. Pick "Change" as event and jQuery selector if you go for a dynamic action, and as true action pick execute javascript code. You can then put the function code in there. With the exception that `$(this)`will need to be `$(this.triggeringElement)`

Comment: `description` column in my tabular form is `autocomplete`. it is also use ajax call. when i select description from autocomplete list, this is not working. if i write full description without selecting from autocomplete list, this is work. how could i solve this issue ?

Comment: What sort of autocomplete do you have? A jQuery one? If yes, do you have something bound to the events of the autocomplete which could cancel something out? The change event should simply fire for an autocomplete item, i just tried it myself with both the change event for the autocomplete and a change event bound to the item.

Comment: jQuery one with Ajax call back

Comment: This my code. Download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vq3yralf5qzxjtd/jQuery_Ajax.txt)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with it at first. I take it you bound the change event with a dynamic action? It does not fire after selecting an item from the autocomplete dropdown, but it does when not picking? Are you sure and have you tried with an alert/console.log line? If all looks fine, could you try to change the focus option of your autocomplete: `focus: function(event,ui){event.preventDefault();}` instead of return false? Maybe add a function for the change event too, just to debug: `change: function(){ alert("autocomp change");}`